# Remove space between <select> tag and options in MS Edge browsers

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I am not sure if this is new but I recently noticed that for MS Edge browsers there is a space between the `<select>` tag and its options.

[image]

I know there are really few options for style `<select>` elements.

Is there any alternative to remove this? Preferable without extra libraries.

Example (check this in MS Edge):

```html
<body style="background: blue;">
  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: You could wrap the options in a div, and set a negative top margin equal to the gap on that div

Comment: @sarahm16 can you extend? I think wrap options in a div is not valid HTML

Comment: Check your margin and padding. Also see how edge renders a select on a page without any css, I think your css screws this up. Last point: edge should render it the same as chrome, they use same rendering engine.

Comment: @cloned the example is without CSS (only a background in the body to make the problem visible). Edge actually do not render the same as chrome unfortunately.

Comment: On my Windows10 Edge and Chrome display select differently. FF and Edge are showing a gap, Chrome isn't. (and for good measure, IE11 conjoins things so not only no gap, but no individual select remaining either). This test done with no additional CSS of any kind.

Comment: Did you zoom in? I am on phone so can't check but there shouldn't be that issue :/

Comment: @cloned I added a snippet but I am unsure if this will happen for mobile browsers. In my case this only appears in Edge Desktop.

Comment: I will check it on Monday

Comment: In my opinion, this should be by design. I found that when the screen is zoomed, this space part is a fixed height. Although Edge is now based on Chromiun, due to the development and design concepts of different vendors (Google and Microsoft), for end users, there will be differences in their experience.

Comment: This is really weird, I never noticed this before. But you are right, edge renders it this way. I would say leave it at this, or use a JS plugin to render custom selectboxes. I couldn't find a solution on how to remove this space.